# Recursively change directories and execute a command in each

Tags: bash

I'm trying to write a bash script to recursively go through a directory and execute a command at each landing. Each folder from the base has the prefix "lab" and I only want to recurse through those folders. An example without recursively going through the folders would be:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd $HOME/gpgn302/lab00
scons -c
cd $HOME/gpgn302/lab00/lena
scons -c
cd $HOME/gpgn302/lab01
scons -c
cd $HOME/gpgn302/lab01/cloudpeak
scons -c
cd $HOME/gpgn302/lab01/bear
scons -c
```

And while this works, if I want to add more directories in say lab01, I would have to edit the script. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 6):

There are a few close suggestions here, but here's one that actually works:

```
find "$HOME"/gpgn302/lab* -type d -exec bash -c 'cd "$1"; scons -c' -- {} \;
```

Comment: Why pass {} as an argument. Why not just embed it in the string where $1 is? I'm curious b/c I've used the latter approach more than once, and not the pass- by-argument approach.

Comment: Because it'll fail if the directory name contains backticks or dollar signs, and worse, allows code injection.

Answer (score 3):

Use `find` for this kind of task:

```
find "$HOME/gpgn302" -name 'lab*' -type d -execdir scons -c . \;
```

Comment: `exec` doesn't change directories; `execdir` does.

Comment: Nor does it try to limit it to the lab dirs

Comment: It still doesn't work. It doesn't run the command in `$HOME/gpgn302/lab00/lena`.

Comment: @theotherguy I don't have `scons` installed, so I can't check right now, but if I understand the man page correctly using "." should also remove targets below the current directory.

Answer (score 2):

It's easy to use `find` to locate and run commands.

Here's an example which changes into the correct directory before running your command:

```
find -name 'lab*' -type d -execdir scons -c \;
```

**Update:**
As per thatotherguy's comment, this doesn't work.  The `find -type d` will only return directory names, however `-execdir` command operates on the subdirectory containing the matched file, so in this example the `scons -c` command would be execute in the parent directory of the found `lab*` directory.

Use thatotherguy's method or this which is very similar:

```
find -name 'a*' -type d -print -exec bash -c 'cd "{}"; scons -c'  \;
```

Comment: @thatotherguy You're right.  I'll leave some notes as to why this doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it with bash:

```
#!/bin/bash

# set default pattern to `lab` if no arguments
if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
  pattern=lab
fi

# get the absolute path to this script
if [[ "$0" = /* ]]
then
  script_path=$0
else
  script_path=$(pwd)/$0
fi

for dir in $pattern*; do
  if [ -d $dir ] ; then
    echo "Entering $dir"
    cd $dir > /dev/null
    sh $script_path dummy
    cd - > /dev/null
  fi  
done
```